# Using the Try-Convert Tool for migrating from .net to .net core Multiple installs of MSBuild

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, command-prompt

I have installed the Try-Convert tool, and when i go to the root of my project and execute the try-convert command - I get multiple installs of MSBuild detected, Please select one..

[image]

I can't find a solution on the internet so far..

And when i try to type in the version, i get Input not accepted, try again.

[image]

I have tried Try-Convert -m C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.404 but it comes up with an error saying - ***U*nrecognized command or argument 'Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.404'****

[image]

Comment: Just type `1`, `2` or `3` into the console and pressing enter

Comment: That didnt work - just says System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Multiple MSBuild solution files were found. Please specify which to use with '-w'.

Comment: @sinfella Did you get a solution to the above question or tried running locally?

Comment: He's missing quotes around the file path